# Mysql group by - order by not working

Tags: mysql, left-join

Can't figure this out; I have a query with GROUP BY, but the ORDER BY is not working (is ordering accordingly to the GROUP BY field).

This is the query:

```
SELECT item.*, 
  customer.title AS customertitle
FROM gallery_items AS item 
LEFT JOIN gallery_customers AS customer ON (customer.id = item.customerid) 
WHERE item.published=1 
GROUP BY item.id 
ORDER BY item.created DESC
```

I have little knowledge of mysql; what's going on here and how can I sort on the created-field?

Thanks!

Comment: If id a primary key in the table gallery_items, you don't need to group by item.id. In case `GROUP BY` is removed `ORDER BY` will work as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the GROUP BY and it should work.

GROUP BY is useful when you want to use aggregate functions such as MIN or MAX to get a single value for each group, however it seems that you aren't doing that here.

Comment: Well... That's not absolutely correct. What if the id is not primary key but just a regular column? In his case it may work, but only if `id` is primary. Don't you agree?

Comment: @RRStoyanov: If either item.id or item.customerid is non-unique then the GROUP BY is incorrect and will give an indeterminate result (other databases would reject the query entirely). Only in the case that both are unique is it valid to include GROUP BY, but then it is redundant as it won't change the result. So either way it shouldn't be there. GROUP BY should normally only be used together with aggregate functions.